# Soundcloud error 500 on playlist api

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I'm trying, via api, to get my playlists.

I set up the requests via PHP and every time I send this request (translated for testability)

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/radio-pnr/playlists.json?consumer_key=XXXXX

The server returns

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017 13:25:17 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0 Via: 1.1
>   008ae64ab7020a9aecc4c202669805d4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>
> X-Amz-Cf-Id: OFnsjEnoSzB5CtgGJ0eyJn9v4yWOp9PSzPBKZIbwr4fwz3rX9GEi-g==
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
>
> Server:  am/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same error using curl at the command-line. Looking at that user, I think the number of playlists and tracks per playlist could be causing timeouts on the server-side.

Comment: you're brilliant. I'll investigate. Thanks for pointing me out

Comment: I've tried, seems to be a problem related to the playlist service itself. If i request all the tracks, the api endpoint serves me the full list (7000+ tracks)